# Find first non zero index of Array in Excel

Tags: excel

My formula is as follows:

```
=function({0,-24,-25,-101,105})
```

I simply want to return -24, which is the first non-zero value and I'm not sure how to do so. Note that the array {0, -24 ...} must be directly typed into the formula and is not located in any cell on the spreadsheet. There could also be multiple zeros preceding the array and not just one.

Comment: `directly typed into the formula and is not located in any cell`???

Comment: For example: =max({1,2,3}). The array {1,2,3} is directly typed into the formula. Instead of getting the maximum, I want to get the first non-zero value (I cannot change the array directly).

Comment: Ohhh ok. Now I get it. You know saying `not located in any cell` is _very_ confusing XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX({0,-24,-25,-101,105},MATCH(TRUE,{0,-24,-25,-101,105}<>0,0))
```